# GAE Datastore read/write latency in non-production app versions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Being awawre of the fact that datastore is shared among all app versions on Google AppEngine, I have recently created a separate version of my app which I use for special purposes.

I have noticed, however, that, despite the fact this version is executing almost the same code as the production version, it responds to client requests significantly slower than production; certain requests often result in `DeadlineExceededError`.

A typical error that I can now observe in my logs looks like this:

```
...
friend.put()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1070, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1601, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1234, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 576, in check_success
    self.wait()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 550, in wait
    assert self.__rpc.state != apiproxy_rpc.RPC.IDLE, repr(self.state)
DeadlineExceededError
```

My question is: can it be the case that GAE datastore operations latency consistently increases on non-production app versions? If so, is there a good way to solve this problem while still using non-production app version?

Comment: I've never encountered something like that, I always test new versions separately and works like the default version.

Answer (score 0):

Does the log entry for those entries with `DeadlineExceededError` also include this message?

`This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.`

Maybe that's what is causing it to go over the time limit.

Another option is to set up [Appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) and see exactly where the time is being spent.

Comment: No, it doesn't - just the pure error message I pointed out above